# Ubuntu Settings freezing when setting up 3 monitors after NVIDIA driver installation

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, displaylink

I installed Displaylink and successsfully set up 3 additional monitors in Ubuntu 20.

[image: Image 0]

Then I installed the NVIDIA driver for RTX 2060 with `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440`.

However, I had to reboot and now monitors are back aligned.

[image: Image 2]

When I try to set up the "cross" position again, Settings freeze after clicking in `Apply` and I am unable to do it.

I tried to remove NVIDIA driver, reinstall Displaylink, reinstall Settings (`sudo apt-get install unity-control-center`) but nothing worked.

I'm wondering if NVIDIA driver altered any system file, because even after removing the GPU driver, system Settings freezes. After the fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.4 + Displaylink and before the NVIDIA driver installation, everything was perfect.

I even tried to set monitors manually in the command line with `xrandr` but it froze also.

Any idea of what else can I do ?

Comment: May I ask why you're using the 440 Nvidia driver? Do you have a specific reason? 440 is outdated, and driver 470 is tested and recommended for 20.04. I'm not familiar with 440 but it may be a part of the issue you're having.

Comment: Thanks @ScarletNyaa I'll try and let you know.

Comment: Why do you need nvidia driver if everything is perfect without it?